# retrieve output logfile value from logger

Tags: python, logging

i try to use python logging module to create a timed rotating handler to some sort cache to a file.

eventually i need to know what is the cache file name.
i cannot find any property in logger to retrieve it.

so i create kind of monkey job to overload the logger for later retrieve.
anybody know a better solution?

```
    def srvcacheconfig(**kwargs):
        srv_name = kwargs['server_name']
    #     cache_path = CACHEPATH
    #     ans=dict()
        cache_filename = srv_name+CACHE_EXT
        cache_logger = logging.getLogger(srv_name)
        cache_logger.propagate = False

        #monkey job
        cache_logger.cache_name = cache_filename

        cache_format = logging.Formatter("%(message)s")
    #     cache_handlers = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(cache_filename, when = 'midnight', backupCount = 366)
        cache_handlers = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(cache_filename, when = 'M', interval = 1, backupCount = 200)

        cache_handlers.setFormatter(cache_format)
        cache_logger.addHandler(cache_handlers)

#       consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
#        cache_logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)


        cache_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        return cache_logger
```

thank you very much

Comment: Somehow I don't get your question. What exactly are you trying to do, and what exactly is not working?

Comment: to instantiate a file logger i need to specific the filename. this situation i declare a timedrotatingfile logger with it handler class. after that i need to know the filename of my logger. 
my question was , how i get the file name of my filename from my logger instance.
my solution is during instantiate the handler with the filename, i overload the logger instance with cache_name property for me to retrieve the filename later on.
all in all, my question is how to get the filename of my logger file from logger instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`TimedRotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) has a property named `baseFilename`, which holds the name of the logfile. However, this is [*not documented*](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l998) and *may* therefore change without further notice.

From this property you can get the logfile's name:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

my_logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
my_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('logfile.log')
my_logger.addHandler(my_handler)

def get_filename(some_logger):
    return [some_handler.baseFilename
            for some_handler in some_logger.handlers
            if isinstance(some_handler, TimedRotatingFileHandler)]

print(get_filename(my_logger))  # ['/home/finwood/temp/so/logfile.log']
```

Comment: thank you very much. you answered all of my questions!!! very nice link to  the documentation.